# How to remove sectional breaks from word document using python-docx

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I am trying to remove the sectional breaks from a word document. For this I am trying to remove the sectPr attribute from the xml generated through python-docx. This is the xml which is generated :

```
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml/cex" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se w16cid w16 w16cex wp14">
  <w:body>
    <w:p w14:paraId="0F1E22A8" w14:textId="1CB95B52" w:rsidR="006F7C29" w:rsidRDefault="00B46A6B">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="006F7C29">
          <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
          <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
          <w:cols w:space="708"/>
          <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>math</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w14:paraId="3FE55637" w14:textId="789D24FC" w:rsidR="003660CC" w:rsidRPr="003660CC" w:rsidRDefault="003660CC" w:rsidP="008F17C5"/>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="003660CC" w:rsidRPr="003660CC" w:rsidSect="008F17C5">
      <w:type w:val="evenPage"/>
      <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
      <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
      <w:cols w:space="708"/>
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

I have written the following code to remove sectPr:

```
def identifySbr(doc):
    allp=len(doc.paragraphs)
    document_xml = doc.element.xml


    for i in range(0,allp):
        c = doc.paragraphs[i]._p.xpath("./w:pPr/w:sectPr")

        if len(c)>0:
            ca = doc.paragraphs[i]._p.xpath("./w:pPr/w:sectPr")[0]
            ca.attrib.pop(qn("w:sectPr"))
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ca.attrib.pop(qn("w:sectPr"))
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 2449, in lxml.etree._Attrib.pop
KeyError: '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}sectPr'
```

can anybody please help me resolve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to remove section breaks, which often contain important formatting as well as headers and footers? Unless they contain none of this, you are likely to get unpredictable results when you succeed in removing them.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I do want to remove the header and footer content and replace them with new content completely. Due to this I am removing the old sectional breaks and adding new ones later. These new sectional breaks do have new header and footer content which I want. What else might get affected if I remove the sectional breaks?

Comment: Other things in  section breaks: Even/odd and different first page settings for headers/footers, page size, orientation, and margins, columns. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm See also: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF and http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings  (Disclosure: these are all links to pages on my website.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<w:sectPr>` item you are trying to remove is an *element*, not an *attribute* (of an element). So the error message is telling you that the `w:sectPr` element has no `w:sectPr` attribute, which of course it doesn't.

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
def remove_all_but_last_section(document):
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        p = paragraph._p
        sectPrs = p.xpath("./w:pPr/w:sectPr")
        if not sectPrs:
            continue
        sectPr = sectPrs[0]
        sectPr.getparent().remove(sectPr)
```

An alternative implementation which is perhaps a bit more elegant and definitely would perform better (although it would probably be very fast either way unless the document was huge):

```
def remove_all_but_last_section(document):
    sectPrs = document._element.xpath(".//w:pPr/w:sectPr")
    for sectPr in sectPrs:
        sectPr.getparent().remove(sectPr)
```

Comment: thank you for the insight. Your solution is definitely solving the issue.

Comment: Related to this, how would you remove Page Breaks from a document? 
So the XML `w:br w:type="page"`